# Server not getting data from client - JAVA

Tags: java, server, client

This is my server code:

```
package ServerSideHammingCodeCheckingAndResponse;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server
{    
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private int port;

public Server(int port)
{
    this.port = port;
}

public void start() throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("Server starts at port:" + port);
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

    System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

    sendMessage(client, "This is Hamming Code Checking.");

    boolean checkInput = false;
    String input = null;
    while (!checkInput)
    {
        input = getMessage(client);

        if(input.length() == 7 && input.matches("[01]+"))
            checkInput = true;
        else
            sendMessage(client, "invalid");
    }
    sendMessage(client, input);
}

private void sendMessage(Socket client, String message) throws IOException
{
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));

    writer.write(message);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}

private String getMessage(Socket client) throws IOException
{
    String userInput;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    userInput = reader.readLine();
    return userInput;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int portNumber = 9987;

    try {
        Server socketServer = new Server(portNumber);
        socketServer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

This is my client code:

```
package ClientSideDataTransmitter;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client
{
private String hostname;
private int port;
Socket socketClient;

public Client(String hostname, int port)
{
    this.hostname = hostname;
    this.port = port;
}

public void connect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException
{
    System.out.println("Attempting to connect to " + hostname + ":" + port);
    socketClient = new Socket(hostname, port);
    System.out.println("\nConnection Established.");
}

public void readResponse() throws IOException
{
    String userInput;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketClient.getInputStream()));

    System.out.print("Response from server: ");
    while ((userInput = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(userInput);
    }
}

public void sendData() throws IOException
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socketClient.getOutputStream()));
    System.out.println("Enter a 7-bits binary as message to server:\n");
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    writer.write(input);
    writer.flush();
}

public static void main(String arg[])
{
    Client client = new Client ("localhost", 9987);
    try {
        client.connect();
        client.readResponse();
        client.sendData();
        client.readResponse();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Host unknown. Cannot establish connection");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot establish connection. Server may not be up." + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

I havent finish up the code so please ignore minor mistakes in the code.

When I start Server, then Client, and send an input from Client to Server. Server seems not getting the data from Client since I send back that input from server to client to print it out, it prints nothing.

I think there may be problems in the method getMessage() in the server code but I cant fix it. Please help me fix the code. Many thanks!

Server:

```
Server starting at port 9987
Waiting for client...
```

Client:

```
Attempting to connect to localhost:9987

Connection Established.
Response from server: This is Hamming Code Checking.
Enter a 7-bits binary as message to server:

1234567
Response from server:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On top of Shriram suggestions I advise you to use PrintWriter here to avoid closing connection. It's also somewhat more convenient to use. Here's working example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private int port;

    public Server(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void start() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Server starts at port:" + port);
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

        System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

        sendMessage(client, "This is Hamming Code Checking.");

        boolean checkInput = false;
        String input = null;
        while (!checkInput) {
            input = getMessage(client);

            if (input.length() == 7 && input.matches("[01]+"))
                checkInput = true;
            else
                sendMessage(client, "invalid");
        }
        sendMessage(client, input);
    }

    private void sendMessage(Socket client, String message) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        writer.println(message);
    }

    private String getMessage(Socket client) throws IOException {
        String userInput;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        userInput = reader.readLine();
        return userInput;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int portNumber = 9987;

        try {
            Server socketServer = new Server(portNumber);
            socketServer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
    private String hostname;
    private int port;
    Socket socketClient;

    public Client(String hostname, int port) {
        this.hostname = hostname;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void connect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Attempting to connect to " + hostname + ":" + port);
        socketClient = new Socket(hostname, port);
        System.out.println("\nConnection Established.");
    }

    public void readResponse() throws IOException {
        String userInput;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketClient.getInputStream()));

        System.out.print("Response from server: ");
        userInput = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(userInput);
    }

    public void sendData() throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socketClient.getOutputStream(), true);
        System.out.println("Enter a 7-bits binary as message to server:\n");
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        writer.println(input);
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Client client = new Client("localhost", 9987);
        try {
            client.connect();
            client.readResponse();
            client.sendData();
            client.readResponse();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Host unknown. Cannot establish connection");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot establish connection. Server may not be up." + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code now stops at printing "This is Hamming Code Checking". The method sendData() on client doesnt run. How to fix it next?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is `writer.close()` in `sendMessage()` will internally close the writer objects. Your server program will be closed and no longer in connection to accept the connections.

Comment: I did try removing writer.close() in sendMessage() and it stops at Connection Established on client ???

Comment: That's because of while ((userInput = reader.readLine()) != null)  line. Because after reading response from server again waits in the loop continuously. You are not using multithreading in your programming. Better to use different threads to write and read.

Answer (score 0):

You're losing data by creating a new `BufferedReader` per message. You need to use the same one for the life of the socket. Ditto 'PrintWriter` or whatever you use to send.